# PVZ GW troubleshooting

Tags: technical-issues, plants-vs-zombies-garden-warfare

When somebody in my family plays Plants Vs Zombies: Garden Warfare on the PS3 it says I need a PSN account so I made one for my kid. He's only 9 and  we set him up a sub account for him and I figured it would work, since he is only 9 years old and the game is rated PEGI 7. However, it says there are parental controls setup, even though none are in use. I've also heard you needed to be 13 to have an EA/Origin account, so I forged the age and made a new account with age 13. Same error came up.

One guaranteed solution would be to give my son a master account (age 18 or over) but there is no way am I risking that and putting my child in grave danger (PVZ pun intended). Any solutions?

Comment: This seems somewhat sketchy. Not sure if we help with account stuff when it involves the ages on those accounts being indicated as made-up.

Comment: :( fair enough ; I blame the age rating on the game itself